# image keep half screen

Tags: android, image, screen

[image]My goal: button1 on top, button2 on down. ImageView must keep half screen. Other textView are to keep other half screen. webview is invisible. I can't keep imageview half screen and other textview to other half screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#103080"
        android:text="yes"
        android:textColor="#f7d404" />

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="146dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/info2"
            android:textColor="#103080"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#103080"
            android:text="Exit"
            android:textColor="#f7d404" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use relative layout rather than linear layout and why do you have linear layout twice within one view. remove the second one and implement anything from it into the first linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#103080"
    android:text="yes"
    android:textColor="#f7d404" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/info2"
            android:textColor="#103080"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#103080"
            android:text="Exit"
            android:textColor="#f7d404" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

With weight sun function in main layout i.e. LinearLayout , you can achieve this.
like keep main layout as LinearLayout with its vertical orientation and weight sum as 100 or 1. and then you can divide this weight sum in subsequent child components.like,

`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="100" >

    <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#103080"
         android:text="yes"
         android:textColor="#f7d404"
         android:layout_weight="10" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_weight="40" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView3"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:text="TextView"
         android:layout_weight="10" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/info2"
            android:textColor="#103080"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#103080"
            android:text="Exit"
            android:textColor="#f7d404"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:background="#103080"
    android:text="yes"
    android:textColor="#f7d404" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="146dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/info2"
        android:textColor="#103080"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#103080"
        android:text="Exit"
        android:textColor="#f7d404" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Button2 is not on the bottom.